# What Is The Use Case Of Options Argument Added to http.createServer Method

Tags: javascript, node.js

Upon going through the node.js documentation I realized the **createServer** method on the **http** module has been updated to receive an **options** argument. It was not included before in previous versions of node.js if I remember correctly

```
http.createServer([options][, requestlistener])
```

Link: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener

It is not clear what the options can be used for but it is an object that has the properties **IncomingMessage** and **ServerResponse**.

I just want clarification on what it can be used for and a code example.

Comment: "*specifies the class to be used*" sounds very much like that you can pass a constructor of your own `IncomingMessage` and/or `ServerResponse` (sub)class, which will then be used for creating the `req, res` arguments to be passed to the request listener.

Comment: @Bergi a code example will be helpful. I'm confused...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server does create an `IncomingRequest` and `ServerResponse` instance for each request it receives, and passes them to the `request` event listener - they are the objects that you receive in the typical `(req, res) => { … }` functions.

In particular they are instantiated [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/bdf07f4317ce738bbe56c5b91aaebf35d15052a8/lib/_http_common.js#L91) and [there](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6ab28486c3042bb1fec7f7714910def37c3a81ac/lib/_http_server.js#L706), in the internals of the http library (and also, similarly, in the https and http2 libraries). The `createServer` options allow you to customise which classes exactly are used for these objects. A simple example:

```
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, createServer } from 'http';

class MyIncomingMessage extends IncomingMessage {
  …
}
class MyServerResponse extends ServerResponse {
  …
}

const server = createServer({
  IncomingMessage: MyIncomingMessage,
  ServerResponse: MyServerResponse,
});
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  console.assert(req instanceof MyIncomingMessage);
  console.assert(res instanceof MyServerResponse);

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.end('Hello!');
});
```

A simple customisation would be adding your own methods, and otherwise inheriting from the builtin default classes. You could also overwrite some methods, or you could roll your own implementation.

Comment: maybe could you complete you answer with the code that could go inside MyIncomingMessage and MyServerResponse?

Comment: @Byron2017 If you don't know what code should go in there, you probably just shouldn't use those options at all. I don't know your use case so I can't give you an example.